# Wants to save Image of my user on 2nd sever MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, model-view-controller

I am currently working on a project in which we want to store image on separate sever. I don't now how to connect both the server so that i can easily save image on remote server.

```
  if (Request.Files.AllKeys.Any())
        {
            foreach (string fileName in Request.Files)
            {
                HttpPostedFileBase file = Request.Files[fileName];
                string oldFileName = file.FileName;
                NewFileName = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();

                string FileExtention = oldFileName.Substring(oldFileName.LastIndexOf('.') + 1);
                if (FileExtention == "blob")
                {
                    FileExtention = "jpg";
                }

                NewFileName = NewFileName + "." + FileExtention;

                var fileSavePath = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~" + filePath + "Document"), file.FileName.Replace(oldFileName, NewFileName));


                file.SaveAs(fileSavePath);


                VisitDocument document = new VisitDocument();
                document.VisitId = vid;
                document.Title = oldFileName.Substring(0, oldFileName.LastIndexOf('.'));
                document.RefPath = (filePath + "Document/" + NewFileName).Replace("/", @"\").Substring(1);
                document.CreatedBy = tempUser.UserId;
                document.CreatedOn = DateTime.Now;
                document.IsDeleted = 0;

                dal.VisitDocuments.Add(document);
                dal.SaveChanges();
            }

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two options to do:

1- Use Web API application to do this task and deploy it on the server you want.

2- Open connection on the server and save the file there but you need to have account on this server and this account has the privileges to write and read.

```
string path = @"\\xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx\Uploads\"; // server IP
if (!System.IO.Directory.Exists(serverPath))
    System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(path );

file.SaveAs(path + FileName);
```